# Replace values of an array based on a vector of indices

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of values and an array of indices. I would like to use indices to generate an array of the same size with values corresponding to the index of the first array:

```
vals = np.array([.2,.3])
ind = np.array([0,0,1,0])
```

expected outcome:

```
np.array([.2,.2,.3,.2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just index your value array with the indices array as they are integers (required for indexing):

```
vals[ind]
```

which produces:

```
array([0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2])
```

as desired.

Comment: ok thanks it works...I tried it before bu it produced an error because one of the arrays was a list, not an np.array

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the NumPy best practice way, but you can do:

```py
[vals[i] for i in ind]
```

```py
new_vals = np.array([vals[i] for i in ind])
```